# Index operation on list column data in polars

Tags: python-polars

I'm working with polars 0.13.46 for Python and I have a column with a list of Strings for which I need to check if a particular String occurs before another. I have created the following code example that works, but needs to break out of polars using `apply`, which makes it very slow.

```py
import polars as pl
from polars import col

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        'str': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'A'],
        'group': [1,1,2,1,2]
    }
).lazy()

df_groups = df.groupby('group').agg([col('str').list().alias('str_list')])
print(df_groups.collect())

pre = 'A'
succ = 'B'

df_groups_filtered = df_groups.filter(
    col('str_list').apply(
        lambda str_list: 
            pre in str_list and succ in str_list and 
            str_list.to_list().index(pre) < str_list.to_list().index(succ)
    )
)

df_groups_filtered.collect()
```

This provides the desired result, which is only the first row of the two rows of the example data:

```
┌───────┬─────────────────┐
│ group ┆ str_list        │
│ ---   ┆ ---             │
│ i64   ┆ list[str]       │
╞═══════╪═════════════════╡
│ 1     ┆ ["A", "B", "B"] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2     ┆ ["C", "A"]      │
└───────┴─────────────────┘
```

I know that I can do

```py
df_groups_filtered = df_groups.filter(
  col('str_list').arr.contains(pre) & col('str_list').arr.contains(succ)
)
```

for the part of checking that both strings are contained, but I couldn't figure out how I can check the order in pure polars.

Are there ways to achieve this natively with polars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to add another solution that I actually ended up adopting. Credits go to @mcrumiller, who posted this on [Github](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/5503).

```py
import polars as pl
from polars import col, when

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "id": [1,2,3,4],
    "list": [['A', 'B'], ['B', 'A'], ['C', 'B', 'D'], ['D', 'A', 'C', 'B']]
})

def loc_of(value):
    # only execute if the item is contained in the list
    return when(col("list").arr.contains(value)).then(
        col("list").arr.eval(
            # create array of True/False, then cast to 1's and 0's
            # arg_max() then finds the first occurrence of 1, i.e. the first occurrence of value
            (pl.element() == value).cast(pl.UInt8).arg_max(),
            parallel=True
        ).arr.first()
    ).otherwise(None) # return null if not found

df.filter(loc_of('A') < loc_of('B'))
```

I really like the simplicity of this approach. Performance-wise it is very similar to the approach of @user18559875.

Answer (score 9):

One way that we can solve this problem is to use the [`arr.eval`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.internals.expr.ExprListNameSpace.eval.html) expression.  The `arr.eval` expression allows us to treat a list as if it were a Series/column, so that we can apply all the same expressions we accustomed to using.

## The Algorithm

```py
(
    df_groups
    .filter(
        pl.col("str_list")
        .arr.eval(
            pl.element().filter(
                ((pl.element() == succ).cumsum() == 0) & (pl.element() == pre)
            )
        )
        .arr.lengths() > 0
    )
    .collect()
    .filter(pl.col("str_list").arr.contains(succ))
)
```

```
shape: (1, 2)
┌───────┬─────────────────┐
│ group ┆ str_list        │
│ ---   ┆ ---             │
│ i64   ┆ list[str]       │
╞═══════╪═════════════════╡
│ 1     ┆ ["A", "B", "B"] │
└───────┴─────────────────┘
```

Note: there is currently a bug in Polars which causes an error when we use

```py
.filter(pl.col("str_list").arr.contains(succ))
```

in lazy mode.  (I'll file a bug report for that.)

## How the algorithm works, in steps

The `arr.eval` expression allows us to treat a list as a Series/column, so that we can apply our usual toolkit of expressions to our problem.

That said, using `arr.eval` can seem a bit confusing at first, so we'll walk through this in steps.

#### As a Series

Let's first see how the algorithm works when our data is a Series/column, and then back into how we code this when the data is in lists.

Let's start with this data.  We'll attempt to find any time that `cat` appears before `dog`.

```py
df_groups = pl.DataFrame([
        pl.Series('cat_dog', ['aardvark', 'cat', 'mouse', 'dog', 'sloth', 'zebra']),
        pl.Series('dog_cat', ['aardvark', 'dog', 'mouse', 'cat', 'sloth', 'zebra']),
        pl.Series('cat_dog_cat', ['aardvark', 'cat', 'mouse', 'dog', 'monkey', 'cat']),
        pl.Series('dog_cat_dog', ['aardvark', 'dog', 'mouse', 'cat', 'monkey', 'dog']),
        pl.Series('no_dog', ['aardvark', 'cat', 'mouse', 'cat', 'monkey', 'zebra']),
        pl.Series('no_cat', ['aardvark', 'mouse', 'dog', 'monkey', 'dog', 'zebra']),
        pl.Series('neither', ['aardvark', 'mouse', 'tiger', 'zebra', 'sloth', 'zebra']),
])
df_groups
```

```
shape: (6, 7)
┌──────────┬──────────┬─────────────┬─────────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ cat_dog  ┆ dog_cat  ┆ cat_dog_cat ┆ dog_cat_dog ┆ no_dog   ┆ no_cat   ┆ neither  │
│ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---         ┆ ---         ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ str      ┆ str      ┆ str         ┆ str         ┆ str      ┆ str      ┆ str      │
╞══════════╪══════════╪═════════════╪═════════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ aardvark ┆ aardvark ┆ aardvark    ┆ aardvark    ┆ aardvark ┆ aardvark ┆ aardvark │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ cat      ┆ dog      ┆ cat         ┆ dog         ┆ cat      ┆ mouse    ┆ mouse    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ mouse    ┆ mouse    ┆ mouse       ┆ mouse       ┆ mouse    ┆ dog      ┆ tiger    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ dog      ┆ cat      ┆ dog         ┆ cat         ┆ cat      ┆ monkey   ┆ zebra    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ sloth    ┆ sloth    ┆ monkey      ┆ monkey      ┆ monkey   ┆ dog      ┆ sloth    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ zebra    ┆ zebra    ┆ cat         ┆ dog         ┆ zebra    ┆ zebra    ┆ zebra    │
└──────────┴──────────┴─────────────┴─────────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

To detect our first occurrence of a `dog`, we'll use the `cumsum` expression on a boolean expression.

```py
pre = "cat"
succ = "dog"
df_groups = df_groups.with_columns(
    (pl.all() == succ).cumsum().suffix('__cumsum')
)
df_groups.select(sorted(df_groups.columns))
```

```
shape: (6, 14)
┌──────────┬─────────────────┬─────────────┬─────────────────────┬──────────┬─────────────────┬─────────────┬─────────────────────┬──────────┬─────────────────┬──────────┬────────────────┬──────────┬────────────────┐
│ cat_dog  ┆ cat_dog__cumsum ┆ cat_dog_cat ┆ cat_dog_cat__cumsum ┆ dog_cat  ┆ dog_cat__cumsum ┆ dog_cat_dog ┆ dog_cat_dog__cumsum ┆ neither  ┆ neither__cumsum ┆ no_cat   ┆ no_cat__cumsum ┆ no_dog   ┆ no_dog__cumsum │
│ ---      ┆ ---             ┆ ---         ┆ ---                 ┆ ---      ┆ ---             ┆ ---         ┆ ---                 ┆ ---      ┆ ---             ┆ ---      ┆ ---            ┆ ---      ┆ ---            │
│ str      ┆ u32             ┆ str         ┆ u32                 ┆ str      ┆ u32             ┆ str         ┆ u32                 ┆ str      ┆ u32             ┆ str      ┆ u32            ┆ str      ┆ u32            │
╞══════════╪═════════════════╪═════════════╪═════════════════════╪══════════╪═════════════════╪═════════════╪═════════════════════╪══════════╪═════════════════╪══════════╪════════════════╪══════════╪════════════════╡
│ aardvark ┆ 0               ┆ aardvark    ┆ 0                   ┆ aardvark ┆ 0               ┆ aardvark    ┆ 0                   ┆ aardvark ┆ 0               ┆ aardvark ┆ 0              ┆ aardvark ┆ 0              │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ cat      ┆ 0               ┆ cat         ┆ 0                   ┆ dog      ┆ 1               ┆ dog         ┆ 1                   ┆ mouse    ┆ 0               ┆ mouse    ┆ 0              ┆ cat      ┆ 0              │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ mouse    ┆ 0               ┆ mouse       ┆ 0                   ┆ mouse    ┆ 1               ┆ mouse       ┆ 1                   ┆ tiger    ┆ 0               ┆ dog      ┆ 1              ┆ mouse    ┆ 0              │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ dog      ┆ 1               ┆ dog         ┆ 1                   ┆ cat      ┆ 1               ┆ cat         ┆ 1                   ┆ zebra    ┆ 0               ┆ monkey   ┆ 1              ┆ cat      ┆ 0              │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ sloth    ┆ 1               ┆ monkey      ┆ 1                   ┆ sloth    ┆ 1               ┆ monkey      ┆ 1                   ┆ sloth    ┆ 0               ┆ dog      ┆ 2              ┆ monkey   ┆ 0              │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ zebra    ┆ 1               ┆ cat         ┆ 1                   ┆ zebra    ┆ 1               ┆ dog         ┆ 2                   ┆ zebra    ┆ 0               ┆ zebra    ┆ 2              ┆ zebra    ┆ 0              │
└──────────┴─────────────────┴─────────────┴─────────────────────┴──────────┴─────────────────┴─────────────┴─────────────────────┴──────────┴─────────────────┴──────────┴────────────────┴──────────┴────────────────┘
```

So our goal will be to see if there are any rows where the value is `cat` and where the `cumsum` on the `dog` expression is also zero.

#### Using lists and `arr.eval`

We'll take this in steps.

First, let's create some data as lists (instead of Series).  I'm also going to eliminate the `lazy` mode, to reduce the clutter.

```py
df_groups = pl.DataFrame({
    'group': ['cat_dog', 'dog_cat', 'cat_dog_cat', 'dog_cat_dog', 'no_dog', 'no_cat', 'neither'],
    'str_list': [
        ['aardvark', 'cat', 'mouse', 'dog'],
        ['aardvark', 'dog', 'mouse', 'cat'],
        ['aardvark', 'cat', 'mouse', 'dog', 'monkey', 'cat'],
        ['aardvark', 'dog', 'mouse', 'cat', 'monkey', 'dog'],
        ['aardvark', 'cat', 'mouse', 'cat', 'monkey'],
        ['aardvark', 'mouse', 'dog', 'monkey', 'dog'],
        ['aardvark', 'mouse', 'tiger', 'zebra'],
    ]
})
df_groups
```

```
shape: (7, 2)
┌─────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────┐
│ group       ┆ str_list                            │
│ ---         ┆ ---                                 │
│ str         ┆ list[str]                           │
╞═════════════╪═════════════════════════════════════╡
│ cat_dog     ┆ ["aardvark", "cat", ... "dog"]      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ dog_cat     ┆ ["aardvark", "dog", ... "cat"]      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ cat_dog_cat ┆ ["aardvark", "cat", ... "cat"]      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ dog_cat_dog ┆ ["aardvark", "dog", ... "dog"]      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ no_dog      ┆ ["aardvark", "cat", ... "monkey"... │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ no_cat      ┆ ["aardvark", "mouse", ... "dog"]    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ neither     ┆ ["aardvark", "mouse", ... "zebra... │
└─────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Now, let's look for any list where `cat` appears before a dog (i.e., the `cumsum` value on `dog` is zero).

```py
pre = "cat"
succ = "dog"
(
    df_groups
    .with_columns(
        pl.col("str_list")
        .arr.eval(
            pl.element().filter(
                ((pl.element() == succ).cumsum() == 0) & (pl.element() == pre)
            )
        )
    )
)
```

```
shape: (7, 2)
┌─────────────┬────────────────┐
│ group       ┆ str_list       │
│ ---         ┆ ---            │
│ str         ┆ list[str]      │
╞═════════════╪════════════════╡
│ cat_dog     ┆ ["cat"]        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ dog_cat     ┆ []             │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ cat_dog_cat ┆ ["cat"]        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ dog_cat_dog ┆ []             │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ no_dog      ┆ ["cat", "cat"] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ no_cat      ┆ []             │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ neither     ┆ []             │
└─────────────┴────────────────┘
```

We see that only three lists have a `cat` before a `dog` appears.

Next, we'll change the `with_columns` to a `filter` to keep only those rows where we found one or more `cat` before a `dog`.

```py
(
    df_groups
    .filter(
        pl.col("str_list")
        .arr.eval(
            pl.element().filter(
                ((pl.element() == succ).cumsum() == 0) & (pl.element() == pre)
            )
        )
        .arr.lengths() > 0
    )
)
```

```
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────┐
│ group       ┆ str_list                            │
│ ---         ┆ ---                                 │
│ str         ┆ list[str]                           │
╞═════════════╪═════════════════════════════════════╡
│ cat_dog     ┆ ["aardvark", "cat", ... "dog"]      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ cat_dog_cat ┆ ["aardvark", "cat", ... "cat"]      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ no_dog      ┆ ["aardvark", "cat", ... "monkey"... │
└─────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────┘
```

And finally, we need to eliminate any rows where a `dog` never appears.

```py
(
    df_groups
    .filter(pl.col("str_list").arr.contains(succ))
    .filter(
        pl.col("str_list")
        .arr.eval(
            pl.element().filter(
                ((pl.element() == succ).cumsum() == 0) & (pl.element() == pre)
            )
        )
        .arr.lengths() > 0
    )
)
```

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────────────┬────────────────────────────────┐
│ group       ┆ str_list                       │
│ ---         ┆ ---                            │
│ str         ┆ list[str]                      │
╞═════════════╪════════════════════════════════╡
│ cat_dog     ┆ ["aardvark", "cat", ... "dog"] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ cat_dog_cat ┆ ["aardvark", "cat", ... "cat"] │
└─────────────┴────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks for this fast and elegant solution as well as the very detailed explanation, @cbilot!

Comment: I should probably mention: the `arr.eval` has a `parallel` keyword.  You might try setting this to `parallel=True` to see if it yields faster performance.

Comment: Good point. For the smaller data set that I'm currently operating on it doesn't make it difference. I assume it will make a difference once the data grows.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the most easy code to process, but this should work reasonably well.
I will see we can add an `arg_where` expression.

If we want to do this fast, we have to create a temporary dummy variable for now (Until we eliminate subexpressions) in polars.

For every element in the list, we filter the values that are not `pre` or `succ` (Or more values, I made it generic to work with `n` number of values).

This should leave these lists:

```
shape: (2,)
Series: 'dummy' [list]
[
    ["A"]
    ["A", "B"]
]
```

Then in the `filter` operation we use a `fold` to create a boolean predicate unfolded as:

```
dummy[0] == order[0] & dummy[1] == order[1]
```

We could write this out, which would be a bit more readable, but then it would not work on `n` number of elements.

```py
pre = 'A'
succ = 'B'

order = [pre, succ]


# we first compute a dummy 
# we do that sequentally because it can be expensive to compute it multiple times.
df_groups.with_columns([
    
    # we use arr.eval
    # and run the search in parallel
    pl.col("str_list").arr.eval(
        expr=pl.element().filter(pl.element().is_in(order)).head(2),
        parallel=True
    ).alias("dummy"),
]).filter(
    # we use a fold because this generic for any number of elements
    pl.fold(acc=True, 
           f=lambda acc, e: acc & e, 
           exprs=[pl.col("dummy").arr.get(i) == order[i] for i in range(0, len(order))]
           )
).drop("dummy")
```

Comment: Thanks Ritchie! I had to change the expression to only work on unique elements to also support cases like ["A", "A", "B"]. It's definitely faster than the `apply` version, but slightly slower that cbilot's suggestion. So I will go with his solution.

Comment: There’s a new `arg_where` function that may make this even faster.  You may want to check that out in upcoming releases.  https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/3757

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it that uses `explode`, `pivot`, and `join` as the primary strategy.

If we start from the same cat/dog df as @user18559875 then we get

```
df_groups = pl.DataFrame({
    'group': ['cat_dog', 'dog_cat', 'cat_dog_cat', 'dog_cat_dog', 'no_dog', 'no_cat', 'neither'],
    'str_list': [
        ['aardvark', 'cat', 'mouse', 'dog'],
        ['aardvark', 'dog', 'mouse', 'cat'],
        ['aardvark', 'cat', 'mouse', 'dog', 'monkey', 'cat'],
        ['aardvark', 'dog', 'mouse', 'cat', 'monkey', 'dog'],
        ['aardvark', 'cat', 'mouse', 'cat', 'monkey'],
        ['aardvark', 'mouse', 'dog', 'monkey', 'dog'],
        ['aardvark', 'mouse', 'tiger', 'zebra'],
    ]
})
```

Taking this step by step, first we want an `id` column so we use `with_row_count`

```
df_groups.with_row_count('id')
```

We then want to use `explode` to convert the `str_list` into a bigger df where each value of that nested list becomes its own row

```
df_groups.with_row_count('id').explode('str_list')
```

from here we add another index to capture the ordering of the list

```
df_groups.with_row_count('id').explode('str_list').with_row_count('order')
```

Now we do a `groupby` on our first `id` and our `str_list` column which we'll then aggregate by the minimum value of order (ie, get the index value of the underlying list)

```
df_groups.with_row_count('id').explode('str_list').with_row_count('order') \
         .groupby(['id','str_list']).agg(pl.col('order').min())
```

Since we only care about the relative position of dogs and cats, we filter to only get dogs and cats, which we could/should actually do as early as possible which would be right after the explode (I'm putting it after the `with_row_count` in case the true ordinal position matters.

```
df_groups.with_row_count('id').explode('str_list').with_row_count('order') \
         .filter(pl.col('str_list').is_in(['cat','dog'])) \
         .groupby(['id','str_list']).agg(pl.col('order').min())
```

The next thing we want is to filter for when cat is less than dog so we pivot so there's a dog and a cat column from which we can simply filter for when `cat`<`dog` and/or when `dog` isn't present.

```
df_groups.with_row_count('id').explode('str_list').with_row_count('order') \
    .filter(pl.col('str_list').is_in(['cat','dog'])) \
    .groupby(['id','str_list']).agg(pl.col('order').min()) \
    .pivot(index='id', columns='str_list', values='order') \
    .filter((pl.col('cat')<pl.col('dog')) | (pl.col('dog').is_null()))
```

but that's not what you actually want, it just gives you the row of what you want so we just select the `id` column and join it back to the original.

```
df_groups.with_row_count('id').join(
    df_groups.with_row_count('id').explode('str_list').with_row_count('order') \
        .filter(pl.col('str_list').is_in(['cat','dog'])) \
        .groupby(['id','str_list']).agg(pl.col('order').min()) \
        .pivot(index='id', columns='str_list', values='order') \
        .filter((pl.col('cat')<pl.col('dog')) | (pl.col('dog').is_null())).select('id'),
    on='id').select(pl.exclude('id'))
```