# Find Index in list column based on a different column in Python Polars

Tags: python, python-polars

I'm working with Python Polars 0.19.7

My minimal example is a Dataframe with 2 columns - the first column is a date and the second column a list of dates, where the dates in each row are unique. The list of dates in second column are already sorted (in ascending order).

The goal is to find the smallest index (i) of Column 2, where the date in Column 1 is less than i-th list element in each row.

```py
import polars as pl
from datetime import date

df = pl.DataFrame({
    'ref_date': [ date(2023, 9, 10), date(2023, 5, 15) ],
    'date_list': [ 
        [ date(2023, 1, 1), date(2023, 5, 1), date(2023, 12, 31) ],
        [ date(2023, 4, 15), date(2023, 6, 18), date(2023, 12, 1) ]
    ]
})
df
```

```
shape(2, 2)
┌─────────────┬────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ ref_date    ┆ date_list                              │
│ ---         ┆ ---                                    │
│ date        ┆ list[date]                             │
╞═════════════╪════════════════════════════════════════╡
│ 2023-09-10  ┆ [2023-01-01, 2023-05-01, 2023-12-31]   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2023-05-15  ┆ [2023-04-15, 2023-06-18, 2023-12-01]   │
└─────────────┴────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

In this example, the result Dataframe should be:

```
shape(2, 3)
┌─────────────┬────────────────────────────────────────┬──────┐
│ ref_date    ┆ date_list                              ┆ i    │
│ ---         ┆ ---                                    ┆ ---  │
│ date        ┆ list[date]                             ┆ u32  │
╞═════════════╪════════════════════════════════════════╪══════╡
│ 2023-09-10  ┆ [2023-01-01, 2023-05-01, 2023-12-31]   ┆ 2    │   
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2023-05-15  ┆ [2023-04-15, 2023-06-18, 2023-12-01]   ┆ 1    │
└─────────────┴────────────────────────────────────────┴──────┘
```

### What I have tried

Using `list.eval()`, I have a solution but it won't take `pl.col` as input. Essentially `ref_date` input is fixed (i.e. `pl.lit` expression), similar to solutions proposed for this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72689281/index-operation-on-list-column-data-in-polars).

Another approach which works uses `pl.explode`, but would be nice to see a solution based on `list.eval`.

Comment: Yeah, referencing other columns inside `list.eval()` is yet to be implemented. There's quite a few issues regarding this functionality e.g. https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/9948 - https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/

Comment: thanks @jquirous for the Ghub reference.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
(df
 .with_row_count('j')
 .with_columns(i=pl.int_ranges(start=0,end=pl.col('date_list').list.lengths()))
 .explode('date_list','i')
 .group_by('j',maintain_order=True)
 .agg(pl.col('ref_date').first(),
      pl.col('date_list'),
      pl.col('i').filter(pl.col('date_list')>pl.col('ref_date')).min())
 .drop('j')
)
```

The thought process starts off with the idea that **you want to explode and not try to deal with `list.eval`**. Secondly, you need the index as the df starts and the index of the `date_list` column which is the first two operations. The third, of course, is the explode itself. The next thing is to group by the original row index and get the minimum value of `i` where `date_list`>`ref_date`.

Comment: Thanks for detailing the explode based approach. Had posed the question originally thinking that a list.eval solution would be more performant. Generally speaking, is that a valid assumption, given there's no current implementation (@jqurious comment to original post).

Comment: In my experience, `list.eval` is slower than exploding. That said I've been avoiding since before they changed the namespace from arr to list. Take a look at [this](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/7124)